# How to make list-group active when click using Angular 5?

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am working on Bootstrap list-group and Angular 5 I'm wondering how to enabled or set to active on specific click on the list-group. Now my problem when I click one of them it enabled all or set them all to active. I just want to enable a specific list on the list-group.

```
-- Bootstrap 4
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>

-- my list
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" [class.active]="!isActive" (click)="onClick(s)" *ngFor="let s of $speech | async" [value]="s.$key">
    {{s.speech}}
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </li>
</ul>

-- from the components

 isActive = false;

  onClick(s) {

    console.log(s)

    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution would be to track the active item by index.

Try with this HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" [class.active]="active === i" (click)="onClick(i)" *ngFor="let s of ($speech | async); let i = index;" [value]="s.$key">
    {{s.speech}}
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and your component:

```
active: number;
onClick(index: number) {
  this.active = index;
}
```